# Best Python Module for Reading Data from .xlsx

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to read in data from .xlsx file and store the data in a list or preferably a dictionary in Python. I see there are many modules built for Python for interacting with .xlsx files like openpyxl, xlsxwriter, xlrd, xlwt, xlutiles, and they're all listed here: http://www.python-excel.org/. I would like to know which one is best for reading in data from the .xlsx and storing the data in a dictionary (preferably) or list?

I'm not trying to manipulate any data. i'm just reading the data in from .xlsx, and then writing it out to a csv file.

Comment: I use openpyxl and have no problems with it.

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (which uses python-excel under the hood). See [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/io.html#io-excel-reader) for more details.

If you plan to manipulate the data and run some calculations, `DataFrame` is a much better data structure than `dict` or `list`.

Comment: I'm not trying to manipulate any data. i'm just reading the data in from .xlsx, and then writing it out to a csv file.

Comment: pandas DataFrame has [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method as well.